# Random selection of dictionary words

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I want to select a number of random words from an array to make a total amount of 36 letters.

At first I tried to select a random word and add it after checking that it's not longer than the amount of free space we have. That was not efficient since the list would fill up and there would only be empty space left for a 2-3 letter word and it takes a long time to find such a short word.

So i decided to only choose six 6-letter words and I'm doing that by generating a random number and then incrementing it by 1 until we find a 6 letter word. It's pretty fast, but the words aren't really that random, often I get words that start from the same letter or only words that start with letters in sequence like  a,b,c or x,y,z.

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    randNumb = rand()%dictionary.size();
    while(dictionary.at(randNumb).length() != 6)
    {
        randNumb++;
    }
    a << "/" << dictionary.at(randNumb) << "/";
}
```

I would like to choose words with different lengths but in favor of performance I'll settle with just the 6-letter words but then i would at least want them to be more randomly selected.

Comment: Note that using modulo to restrict the interval of your random numbers introduces a bias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`rand()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rand.html) generates a number between `0` and [`RAND_MAX`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/).

If `RAND_MAX` is defined as `32767`, then you will not access elements in your dictionary (array?) with indices greater than that.

If you need to generate a random number greater than `RAND_MAX`, then think about summing the result of `n` calls of `rand()`, such that `n * RAND_MAX >= dictionary.size()`. The modulus of this result is then guaranteed to give an index that falls somewhere in the bounds of the entire dictionary.

Comment: Adding the random numbers changes the distribution.

Comment: The distribution of a sum of uniform distributions is a normal distribution, that's true. But the real issue at hand is that the index being generated is within the bounds `[0, RAND_MAX]` and not `[0, dictionary.size()-1]`, and as a result, not all dictionary elements can be accessed. So, regardless of what means are used to generate a random number, it seems important that the output allows access to the whole dictionary.

Comment: It's better to divide a set, rather than sum numbers. As Björn pointed out, summing random numbers changes distribution. The result will be like in a dice game - numbers in the middle are drawn more frequently.

Comment: You can add new random number to previous result. Therefore a shift will become random making index uniform.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time guys, i tried doing as Alex suggested and was happy with the results, but when i tried running the same on android the app would crash.

After some testing i found out that when running in android rand() doesn't have a RAND_MAX limit, so rand()%(dictionary.size()-1); works just fine.

I'm using cocos2dx, so i have no idea if the engine makes this change or the android ndk.

Comment: Perhaps the `RAND_MAX` constant is larger on Android, large enough that `RAND_MAX > dictionary.size()`. You could print it out, to confirm or disprove.

Comment: Modulus skews the distribution, even if `RAND_MAX` is greater than `dictionary.size()`.

Answer (score 3):

You should get a new random number instead of increasing the index. The way you do it, all the strings not matching your criteria "attract" more random numbers, and possibly lead to the following string to have a higher probability of being chosen.

Comment: that doesn't seem to help, while debuging the numbers appear to be random in the 0-40,000 range but dictionary has 250,000 words. i'm guessing that this is because of the short intervals between new random numbers.

Comment: @Arnas: You don't say what makes you think that it "does not work". When youd dictionary is inherently nonrandom (which is very likely by only 250k words), then of course the outcomming strings will be quite nonrandom too.

Answer (score 0):

Even if `RAND_MAX` is greater than `dictionary.size()`, using the `%` operator to select the index leads to a non-uniform distribution.  The modulus will cause the early words to be selected more often than the later words (unless `RAND_MAX + 1` is an integer multiple of `dictionary.size()`).

Consider a simple example:  Assume your dictionary has 10 words, and RAND_MAX is 14.  When `rand()` returns a value from 0 to 9, the corresponding word is chosen directly.  But when `rand()` is 10 through 14, then one of the first five words will be chosen.  So the first five words have twice the chance of being selected than the last five words.

A better way to map [0..`RAND_MAX`] to [0..`dictionary.size()`) is to use division:

```
assert(RAND_MAX + 1 >= dictionary.size());
randNumb = rand() * dictionary.size() / (RAND_MAX + 1);
```

But you have to be careful of integer overflow.  If `RAND_MAX * dictionary.size()` is larger than you can represent in an integer, you'll need to use a larger data type.  Some systems have a function like [`MulDiv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb187717%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for just this purpose.  If you don't have something like `MulDiv`, you can convert to a floating point type and then truncate the result back to an integer:

```
double temp = static_cast<double>(rand()) * dictionary.size() / (RAND_MAX + 1);
randNumb = static_cast<int>(temp);
```

This is *still* an imperfect distribution, but the "hot" words will now be evenly distributed across the dictionary instead of clumping at the beginning.

The closer `RAND_MAX + 1` is to an integer multiple of `dictionary.size()`, the better off you'll be.  And if you can't be sure that it's close to an integer multiple, then you want RAND_MAX to be as large as possible relative to `dictionary.size()`.

Since you don't have much control over `RAND_MAX`, you could consider tweaking `dictionary.size()`.  For example, if you only want six-letter words, then why not strip all the others out of the dictionary?

```
std::vector<std::string> six_letter_words;
std::copy_if(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(),
             std::back_inserter(six_letter_words),
             [](const std::string &word){ return word.size() == 6; });
```

With the reduced set, we can use a more generic algorithm to select the words:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> WordList;

// Returns true with the given probability, which should be 0.0 to 1.0.
bool Probably(double probability) {
    return (static_cast<double>(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX) < probability;
}

// Selects n words from the dictionary using a normal distribution and
// copies them to target.
template <typename OutputIt>
OutputIt Select(int n, const WordList &dictionary, OutputIt target) {
    double count = static_cast<double>(n);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; count > 0.0 && i < dictionary.size(); ++i) {
        if (Probably(count / (dictionary.size() - i))) {
            *target++ = dictionary[i];
            count -= 1.0;
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

The idea is to step through each word in the dictionary and select it with a probability of the number of words you need to pick divided by the number of words left to pick from.  This works well, even if `RAND_MAX` is relatively small.  Overall, though, it's much more computation than trying to randomly select indexes.  Also note that this technique will never choose the same word more than once, where the index mapping technique could.

You call `Select` like this:

```
// Select six words from six_letter_words using a normal distribution.
WordList selected;
Select(6, six_letter_words, std::back_inserter(selected));
```

Also note that most implementations of `rand()` are pretty simplistic and may not give a good normal distribution to begin with.